# Connecting to Gmail from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am attempting to connect to Gmail through Jmeter. I have already imported the security certificate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA` to firefox and I got as far as the Gmail login page. But when I entered my password and click Next nothing happens. I tried clicking Enter as well but it was the same, also the top arrow which takes you to the 'Choose Account' screen also remains unclickable or has no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're doing something very weird.

- Load testing GMail web interface is not the best idea (unless you're a Google employee who is assigned to this task, in this case you can ask your colleagues for help), you will be get banned very soon as load testing of public resources is not something you're allowed to do without explicit permission of the resource's owner as he can treat your activity as a [DNS Attack](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/DNS-attack)
- If you need to fetch an email message from your mailbox (i.e. it contains a registration link) it is better to use [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) which is way faster and reliable than UI-based actions. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for detailed information on configuring JMeter for email connectivity (using Gmail as a reference by the way)
- If you believe that you found an issue having a negative impact on the whole Apache JMeter project you can report it via [JMeter Issue Tracker](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) as ideally JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, the Mail Reader Sampler described in your article 'Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter' is I have been looking for and is the solution for my problem. Thanks a lot for your kind assistance

Answer (score 0):

Read your license agreement for Google.  What you are doing is in direct violation of this agreement.  The only automation which is supported under license are when you use the published interfaces from Google.

As a general rule of thumb, you do not performance test interfaces that you do not own, manage and control or where you have direct written permission from those who do have that authority.  Otherwise, you are engaging in a DDOS against someone else's servers.

Bad Magic.